# .htaccess file ([^\/]+) Not Work, but ([1-9]+[0-9]*) work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My project url is  /catalog/id/

EG:`domain.com/life/women/268/`

I had try many times. Why the `htaccess` can't rewrite the "women", and just rewrite the number '/268/'

Not Work

```
RewriteRule ^life/([^\/]+)/?$ life/list.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^life/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ life/info.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Not Work result

```
Array ( [cat] => list.php )
```

If all use number, Work

```
RewriteRule ^life/([1-9]+[0-9]*)/?$ life/list.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^life/([1-9]+[0-9]*)/([1-9]+[0-9]*)/?$ life/info.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `RewriteRule` rewrites `life/list.php` and `life/info.php`. You should exclude them:

```
RewriteRule ^life/(?!(?:list|info)\.php\/?$)([^\/]+)/?$ life/list.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^life/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ life/info.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It's work! Thanks so much! But, If I have many php file, I need all enter to `(?:list|info) ` ?

Comment: @bb_inger You're welcome! You can use `.*` instead of `(?:list|info)` to match any PHP file.